# I am implementing factory design pattern in Scala and got a compilation error when I tried to access a child class method

Tags: scala, design-patterns

```
 abstract class Computers{
    def hdd:String
    def RAM:String
    def CPU:String
  } 
   class PC(storage:String,memory:String,Cores:String) extends Computers{
   def display:String="This is PC"
    var device="PC"
    def hdd={
      "Hard disk"+" "+storage 
    }
    def RAM={
     memory
    }
    def CPU={
     Cores
    }
  }
   class LAPTOP(storage:String,memory:String,Cores:String) extends Computers{
    def see:String={
      "Hi All"
    }
    var device="Laptop"
    def hdd={
     storage
    }
    def RAM={
     device +":" +memory+" RAM"
    }
    def CPU={
      Cores
    }
  }
  object Computers{    
    def apply(compType:String,storage:String,memory:String,Cores:String)={
      compType match{
        case "PC"=>new PC(storage:String,memory:String,Cores:String)
        case "LAPTOP"=>new LAPTOP(storage:String,memory:String,Cores:String)
      }
    }  
    def main(args:Array[String]){
      val c1=Computers("PC","1 TB","12 GB","5 GHz")
      val c2=Computers("LAPTOP","1 TB","12 GB","5 GHz")
      println(c1.display)
      println(c1.hdd)
      println(c2.RAM)

    }
    
  }
```

I am trieing to implement factory design patterns. But when I tried to call the child class method (display method of PC class)got the below compilation error :
'**Value display is not a member of Computers**'
Can someone help me why I am getting the error

Comment: Hint: what's the return type of `Computers.apply`?

Comment: What is even the point of all that indirection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because when you use the apply method of `Computers` you are getting an instance of type `Computers` which does not have the method `display` defined (as this is only defined on the subclass `PC`)

If you want access to this method you will need to have a `PC` and not a `Computer` type. You could achieve this in a few ways e.g.

- Use the constructor of PC so that you have a type PC
- Pattern match to make sure that a `Computer` is a `PC`
- use `.asInstanceOf[PC]` so that you can call the method (not recommended as this can fail at runtime if whatever you are casting is not actually a `PC`